# PostGIS database connection

Tags: qgis, postgis, connection

I am basic QGIS user and I have database created and data loaded in it. However, when I try to connect to the database, I am getting the following error.

> Connection failed - consult message log for details.

All my credentials are correct.

[image]

Comment: Try switching SSL mode to 'require'

Comment: Have you done the required changes on the PostgreSQL config side (pg_hba.conf file) to allow external connections?

Comment: Can you state the operating system you are working on. And also what versions of QGIS and Postgresql you are using? As stated above you still need to make some edits in the Postgresql config setting.

Comment: Hi,I am using 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor and QGIS 3.18.3 and PostgreSQL is 13.1

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question in response to requests for clarification. You should also post the message log contents.

Comment: Copy/paste the logs, the small comic strip bubble on the bottom right corner. You might have a "postgis" tab with some info.

Comment: Can you connect to the database with psql or pgadmin